# C++ Find execution path on Mac

Tags: c++, linux, macos, directory

Lets say my executable is located at `/Users/test_user/app` on Mac OSX and I am running it from `/Users/test_user/Desktop/run_app`:

```
Desktop run_app$ /Users/test_user/app/exec
```

Within my C++ code how can I find the path to the location of the executable (which in this case would be `/users/test_user/app`)? I need to reference some other files at this path within my code and do not want to put absolute paths within the code as some users might place the folder in a different location.

Comment: Is this a unix executable or a .app bundle?

Answer (score 5):

`man 3 dyld` says:

> _NSGetExecutablePath() copies the path of the main executable into the
>   buffer buf.  The bufsize parameter should initially be the size of the
>   buffer.  This function returns 0 if the path was successfully copied. 
>   It returns -1 if the buffer is not large enough, and * bufsize is set
>   to the size required. Note that _NSGetExecutablePath() will return "a
>   path" to the executable not a "real path" to the executable.  That is,
>   the path may be a symbolic link and not the real file. With deep
>   directories the total bufsize needed could be more than MAXPATHLEN.

```
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buf [PATH_MAX];
  uint32_t bufsize = PATH_MAX;
  if(!_NSGetExecutablePath(buf, &bufsize))
    puts(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Provided I'm understanding you correctly, you should be able to use `NSProcessInfo`'s [`-arguments`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSProcessInfo/arguments) method to get the executable path.

To mix in Objective-C code with C++ code, you can just change the filename extension of the source file in question from .cpp to .mm. Then add the Foundation.framework to the Link Binary With Library build phase of your Target.

[EDIT] updated to show the difference between `argv[0]` and `[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:0]`.

Then to use the code, you could do something like in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // print out raw args
    NSMutableArray *arguments = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            NSString *argument = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[i]];
            if (argument) [arguments addObject:argument];
    }

    NSLog(@"arguments == %@", arguments);

    const char *executablePath =
       [[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:0]
                                             fileSystemRepresentation];

    printf("executablePath == %s\n", executablePath);

    const char *executableDir =
         [[[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:0]
             stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] fileSystemRepresentation];

    printf("executableDir == %s\n", executableDir);

    [pool release];

    return 0;
}
```

If I then `cd` into the parent directory of the executable, and then execute the executable using a relative path:

```
MacPro:~ mdouma46$ cd /Users/mdouma46/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/executablePath-ewememtbkdajumdlpnciyymduoah/Build/Products/Debug

MacPro:Debug mdouma46$ ./executablePath blah blah2
```

I get the following output:

```
2011-08-10 12:59:52.161 executablePath[43554:707] arguments == (
    "./executablePath",
    blah,
    blah2
)

executablePath == /Users/mdouma46/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/executablePath-ewememtbkdajumdlpnciyymduoah/Build/Products/Debug/executablePath

executableDir == /Users/mdouma46/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/executablePath-ewememtbkdajumdlpnciyymduoah/Build/Products/Debug
```

So, while `argv[0]` may not necessarily be a full path, the result returned from `[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:0]` will be.

So, there's `[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:0]`, or a slightly simpler approach is just to use `NSBundle` itself, even if it is a command-line tool (see [What is the "main bundle" of a command-line foundation tool?](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1436/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004115)):

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
const char *executablePath =
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath] fileSystemRepresentation];
[pool release];
```

Comment: I don't think this is a robust solution, because argv[0] is not guaranteed to be an absolute path.

Comment: @sbooth: updated to show the difference between `argv[0]` and the `-arguments` method of `NSProcessInfo`.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks.  I wonder if NSProcessInfo just uses _NSGetExecutablePath under the hood.  I'd also be curious to know how it handles symbolic links and cases where the executable has been unlinked but is still running.  But these are general problems not specific to NSProcessInfo itself.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use the `which` command. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which

Comment: No. No no no no. The `which` command only shows the first result for the command on the user's PATH. This cannot account for launching the command directly (as is done in the question).

Answer (score 2):

If it's a "real" OS X application the proper way to do it is to create a bundle:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html